# Monitoring a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, monitoring

I would like to monitor user behaviors inside a winforms application.

> Is there a general way to hook into the eventing system, without having to write event handlers in every form, or on every button?

I Would like to monitor following events accross the application:

- Windows opened
- Windows closed
- Buttons clicked
- Ideally: time spend in each form

I dont want to subscribe to all the events in all the forms, the application is to big for that. I would just like to hook in and monitor **all** events.

Comment: You can use events of controls and forms.

Comment: I dont want to subscribe to all the events, I would just like to hook in and monitor ALL events. The application is to big to refactor.

Comment: No problem, you don't need to use designer for each buttons of each form. You can simply do it using code. For example you can simply find all controls of `Button` type and handle `Click` event of them using a single method which logs the activity.

Comment: That would still force me to add an event handler to all the buttons. Same for all the windows!

Comment: Probably you think it needs a lot of works. But you can simply have a base `Form` which performs such task for you in a few lines of code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. I posted an answer which shows you can do it using code yourself without using any library. So edit your question and remove the quote part which you are asking for a library.

Comment: I rewrote question accordingly.

Comment: Good job. Know read the answer I posted and let me know if you have any question about the answer. It's really simple and effective.

Comment: Also added this line in constructor `if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write event handles in every form and for every control. You can put the logic in a base `Form` class.

You can simply create a base form for your project and put the logic of log there. In the base form you can subscribe for all kinds of events which you need  using code.

To apply the solution:

- You don't need to change designer or designer generated codes. Just derive all forms from `BaseForm`.
- It can be simply done using a find and replace all command.
- Also to create the class below, don't add a `Form`, just add a class and use the class below:

**Base Form**

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;
        this.Load += BaseForm_Load;
        this.FormClosed += BaseForm_FormClosed;
    }
    private IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control control)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
    }
    void BaseForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log(string.Format("{0} Closed", this.Name));
    }
    void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log(string.Format("{0} Opened", this.Name));
        GetAllControls(this).OfType<Button>().ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Click += ButtonClick);
    }
    void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null) Log(string.Format("{0} Clicked", button.Name));
    }
    public void Log(string text)
    {
        var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "log.txt");
        text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, text);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(file, new string[] { text });
    }
}
```

**Note**

- You can use a log library or any other mechanism for logging.
- You can use any string format for log.
- You can simply add property/method to turn on/ turn off log.
- You may want to log in some other useful events like `Application.ThreadException` event.
- You can simply use a `StopWatch` to calculate the time which user was working with form. Also you can simply log start time and end time and the difference as duration which the user was working with form.
- Here is the usings which you need for the class:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  ```