# Log whether any function is entered

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms app and I want to keep track of what buttons are clicked on. I figure I can put something like a `Console.WriteLine("FUNCTION_NAME");` at the beginning of every function (of course, with FUNCTION_NAME replaced with the actual function's name). My question is: is there a better way? Some sort of programmatic way to grab the function name and do something with it when the function is run?

Comment: As an option take a look at this post: [Monitoring a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018993/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Use `CallerMemberNameAttribute`. Example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of AOP in C#: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx

But the performance will be severely degraded.

Comment: This looks great! But do I still have to put a line inside every function I want to use this in?

Comment: C# does not support Aspect-Oriented Programming, so unfortunately, it's not possible. Well, to be exact, it's technically feasible, but your app will run 1000 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in WPF / MVVM, we'll have a base class for the logger that will use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` , so you don't need to figure out the caller.
Instead of writing it out, you can use a logger (NLog, Log4net, etc), if you create the logger in the class, it will do part of the work automatically as well.

Here's a snippet. Note that this is done for automatic change notifications, but you can use the same for your purposes:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected override void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string property = "")
{
    base.RaisePropertyChanged(property);
}
```

just change the name of the functions obviously, and do what you need in it.