# Track dynamic form automcatically in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application having 2 forms that opens on application start and 3rd form is getting added on runtime.

I have an another class library that currently monitors the activities of a single form. The below code snippet is of application :-

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form[] f = new Form[2];
        f[0] = new Form1();
        f[1] = new Form2();
        f[0].Show();

        AppContext nvca = new AppContext(new Form1(), new Form2());

        Application.Run(nvca);


    }
```

AppContext class is in class library where I am trying to catch all the forms of the application whether it is static or comes at runtime :-

```
public class AppContext:ApplicationContext
    {
        public static Form[] AvailForms = null;
        public  AppContext(params Form[] forms)
        {
            AvailForms = forms;
            UAction ua = new UAction();
            foreach (Form f in forms)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < f.Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    ua.setClickHandlerAsync(f.Controls[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void setClickHandlerAsync(Control item)
        {
            //Have to recursively get all the element to wrap the click listener. 
            item.MouseClick += ClickHandlerAsync;
        }

        private async void ClickHandlerAsync(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Click Handler called");
    }   
    }
```

I am searching for a way through which I can track all the forms that are either already added in application or added at runtime.

I have tried through ApplicationContext, but it failed to capture the win events like click, text change, form events even though all the event handlers has been set properly on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx)? Please elaborate more about what you are going to do and let us know what the problem you are facing with.

Comment: I have revised my post with more details

Comment: You can create a base form for all your form. Then you can track whatever you want from the base form. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39018268/3110834) for example.

Comment: Is there any reason you're passing new instances of Form1 & Form2 for AppContext? Why don't you pass f[0] and f[1] instead?

Comment: @Reza in this way I will be able to track all the forms which will be inherited with  this baseform but what about dynamic forms??

Comment: For dynamic forms also, instead of creating an instance of `Form` class, create an instance of the `BaseForm` class.

Comment: Thank you so much @Reza. it worked!

Comment: You're welcome :)