# How to add a MouseClick event handler for ToolStripItems in ToolStripBar in a more generic way

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I'm trying to add a generic MouseClick event handler for every Control in my C# Winforms Application with a recursive method, but when I get the ToolStripBar the ToolStripItems are not in the Controls list and so they are not intercepted.

Do I have to do a test like this one?

"if the Control is a ToolStripBar then for every Items ToolStripItem attach the event handler"

Is there not a more general way?

thanks a lot

Comment: Buttons on a ToolStrip are not controls. Also it's not good idea to attach a click event handler to all controls in the control tree, for example those up/down buttons or text box in a `NumericUpDown` are three different controls but you never treat them as three different controls, you treat them all as `NumericUpDown` control. The same for a `PropertyGrid` or some other controls.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the requirement. Maybe there is s design-time solution for that or maybe it's an XY problem ...

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for the comment. I'm trying to evaluate this path to intercept all the user's actions in a log. 

You are right in your consideration but I can start from a general case and exclude all the components that is very redundant (and inefficient) to intercept. 

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea in general, but you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018993/3110834). In general, you need to have different logic for different controls. For example for `GetAllControls(this).OfType<Button>()` you need to handle `Click`, for `<ToolStrip>` you need to traverse `ToolStrip` and attach the click event handler to items, `ForTreeView` related event to node, and ...

Comment: the example is interesting. thanks

Comment: By the way, `ToolStrip` has an `ItemClick` event, you can use it, but anyway you need to at least find all the dropdown structures inside it and handle their ItemClick events. The same for menus and context menus.

Comment: But in general, keep in mind "*all the user's actions*" is a bit vague/broad. You need to define "*all the user's actions*" carefully for yourself.

Comment: Yes sure it was a little bit approximating. Now it’a an experiment but I have to define better what actions must be intercepted