# How to listen certain events and know the sender among a lot of elements in an application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, events, listener

I'm working on a vb project that uses WinForms. My project contains many forms and these forms contain many elements (Button, Textbox, CheckBox, ...). I would like when a user does an action, to be able to save what he has done. That's why I need to detect user events (mouse clicks, text input, ...). Once the event is detected, I will register its sender and the type of event.

The problem is therefore that I cannot listen to the events that the user performs among all the forms and be able to link this event to the sender.

Thanks for those who take the time to answer me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add logging features to your application? And you didn't plan for this in advance?

Comment: @Jimi The event type and sender information will be used for other functionality than logging, but that's the idea. And yes I had not planned this in advance.

Comment: Logging is something that should be done carefully and on-purpose wherever you have event handlers/business logic. So the best approach is injecting a logger and adding the call to logger.LogDebug/Info/Error, etc, in all the event handlers and methods in proper line of code.  But if you are looking for a temporary solution (or one for lazy developers), then you can subscribe for the events in base form and some other useful events, like application exception and etc. and log there. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018993/3110834).

Comment: If you want to record User activities (not specifically related to events you have subscribed to), you *could* build an `IMessageFilter` handler class, register your filter (`Application.AddMessageFilter()`) in `Program.cs`, so you receive all keyboard / mouse interactions with the UI. You can listen only to specific messages (e.g., `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEENTER`, `WM_MENUSELECT` and *translate* `WM_NOTIFY` messages). You can get the Control that will receive the message with `Control.FromHandle([Message].hWnd)` -- Relatively far fetched, I admit.

Comment: Another option is to use UI Automation, which is a common tool to test User interaction with an UI. -- Also relatively far fetched, since I don't know what you want to do, in practice, or the actual purpose.

Comment: Thank you everybody ! @Jimi the Control.FromHandle([Message].hWnd) allows to identify the form which is linked to the event but does it allow to identify the element of the form (ex: in my form there is has 3 buttons, can it find the button that triggered the event)?

Comment: Of course. Implementing `IMessageFilter`, you *intercepts* all Windows messages before they're sent to the target recipient. If you, for example, select a Control (e.g., click on a TextBox, moving the Focus), when you receive a `WM_MOUSEDOWN` event, the Handle (in `m.hWnd`) is related to this TextBox. -- Note that you receive **all** the messages that are sent back and forth (some Controls notify the Parent of *what happened*, in specific documented cases), so you need to filter the messages that are meaningful in the context of your operations (some I've mentioned before).

Comment: Thank you very much Marshal @Jimi , that's exactly what I wanted to do, you save me !!!